# create numpy array with varying shape

Tags: python

I want to create a `numpy array` in order to fill it with `numpy arrays`. for example:

```
a = [] (simple array or numpy array) 
b = np.array([[5,3],[7,9],[3,8],[2,1]])
a = np.concatenate([a,b])
c = np.array([[1,2],[2,9],[3,0]])
a = np.concatenate([a,c])
```

I would like to do so because I have wav files from which I extract some features so I can't read from 2 files concurrently but iteratively.
How can I create an empty ndarray with the second dimension fixed e.g. `a.shape = (x,2)` or how can I concatenate the arrays even without the creation of a "storage" array ?

Comment: `a = np.empty((0, 2))`.

Comment: Trying to call `concatenate` incrementally is really, really slow. It's better to build up a list of arrays to concatenate and then `concatenate` them all at once.

Comment: @Psidom Thank you.

Comment: @user2357112 yes. I realized that myself. check my answer. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there are 2 options. 
The first one is: 
a = np.empty((0, 2)) , which creates an empty np array with the first dimension varying.
The second is to create an empty array 
a = [] , append the np arrays in the array and then use np.vstack to concatenate them all together in the end. The latter the most efficient option.

Answer (score 0):

You have to had brackets in concatenate function:

```
b = np.array([[5,3],[7,9],[3,8],[2,1]])
c = np.array([[1,2],[2,9],[3,0]])
a = np.concatenate([b,c])
```

Output:

```
[[5 3]
 [7 9]
 [3 8]
 [2 1]
 [1 2]
 [2 9]
 [3 0]]
```